# Review of Partial Dependence Plot

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have created a partial dependence plot and converted a probability on the y axis. I am systematically going over my variables with the highest importance and see if there are some clear trends in predictor variables and the class. Since I am new to this, I would like to get some feedback from the scientific community.

I have a question mainly on bogs and tidal marsh. I noticed that the line disappears after a certain value on the x axis. Shouldn't the line go all the way to the end of the chart but be at around 0? Does it look like there are some errors in these charts?

[image]

Comment: Are there any points in your data for a Bog above 400 CHM mean (cm)?  Many software packages stop plotting the line in a range where there is no data.  Check the help page in your software.

Comment: Hi, nope there isn't.

Comment: Figured out what I did wrong. I was having troubles making the PDPs from my rf model so I subdivded the dataset based on class then made the PDPs. Don't do that. I discovered the which.class argument and that solved my issues.